Google picker API in Chrome extension MV3
Does anyone know if its possible to use Google picker API in Chrome extension MV3? The biggest issue I have is the fact that MV3 does not allow external script ingestion which is required for GOogle picker API.
I have tried the following:

create popup from chrome extension
Ingest iframe into main tab from content script
Ifratme inside chrome extension

None of the work and throw the same error, which is due to CSP.

The solution is to do it inside an iframe (inside the popup) that is declared as sandbox.

@woxxom I tried that but I'm getting CORS error: from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Any idea how to fix this?

Add the blocked site to host_permissions in manifest.json.

I did, I was actually able to show the drive on sanbox iframe embedded in Chrome extension but none of the files are there due to this error:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://docs.google.com/picker/static/resources/client/js/3900499177-picker_modularized_opdr.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Add content_security_policy for sandbox as shown in that documentation article using connect-src  with your API site instead of example.com.
